# Block Check Character

Tags: c#

Hello
Faced with this problem
is
new byte [] {0x04, 0x30, 0x02, 0x44, 0x03}
Need to define BCc
How can I do?
Thank you in advance
I try this function, but it is not working

```
    private static byte GetBCC(byte[] inputStream)
    {
        byte bcc = 0;
        if (inputStream != null && inputStream.Length > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < inputStream.Length; i++)
            {
                bcc ^= inputStream[i];
            }
        }

        return bcc;
    }
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_check_character

Comment: This question has an elegant haiku-like quality.

Comment: Do you mean to start the loop at 1?